# WPF Static Values as resources and direct content

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a struct that I have created, let's just call it `myDouble`  for the sake of simplicty.

And say it looks like:

```
public struct MyDouble
{
   public static implicit operator MyDouble(double d)
   {
      return new MyDouble{Value=d};
   }
   public static implicit operator double(MyDouble d)
   {
      return d.Value;
   }

   public double Value {get;set;}
}
```

In my UserControl I would like to be able to do something like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <local:MyDouble x:Key="ThritySeven">37</MyDouble>
       <!-- simmular to -->
       <sys:Double x:Key="someNumber">37</sys:Double>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I am getting the error:

```
The type 'MyDouble' does not support direct content.
```

How can I allow it to support direct content?

I looked at the struct Double and it implements these interfaces:

`public struct Double : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<Double>, IEquatable<Double>`

Comment: XAML supports TypeConverters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/typeconverters-and-xaml

Comment: You may use custom structs in XAML for this case like this:

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <local:MyDouble x:Key="ThritySeven" Value="37"/>
       <sys:Double x:Key="someNumber">37</sys:Double>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

Comment: Pls see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-and-custom-classes-for-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8